# Fetching individual inputs from form laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a laravel begineer. I want to fetch the information inputted form the form. the form field names are `name`,`email` and `contact.` which i am trying to fetch just like `$_POST['name'] ,$_POST['email']` in core php

```
{{form::open(array('route'=>'employees.store'))}}
```

the controller store() function: this will fetch all the inputs from the form. i want individual inputs.

```
public function store()
{
    $input=Input::all();
    employee::create($input)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function store()
{
  $input = Input::all();
  $e = new Employee();

  $e->name = $input['name'];
  $e->email = $input['email'];
  $e->contact = $input['contact'];
  ...
  $e->save();
}
```

But shouldn't `store()` receive a Request object like so?

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

Then you could do this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      $input = $request->all();
      $e = new Employee();

      $e->name = $input['name'];
      $e->email = $input['email'];
      $e->contact = $input['contact'];
      ...
      $e->save();
}
```